# How to best deal with Swift evolving very quickly and outdating information?

Tags: discussion, outdated-information

With the much less restrictive NDA, developers are allowed to freely discuss Apple's new programming language Swift online including asking questions on Stack Overflow. Apple has stated that they want to evolve the language very quickly and that they don't promise source compatibility between versions.

At this moment Swift is still in early beta and recently had its array syntax [changed](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=3) between beta 2 and beta 3. There are already ~3500 questions tagged [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift). Approximately 2800 of those were asked before the syntax change and likely contain syntax that no longer compiles. Given that Apple's developer forums already mention new changes like adding access control that hasn't happened yet, this is going to happen at least a couple of more times before the language gets out of beta.

I feel that these questions and answers are adding very little long term value (in fact I would argue that they will be a disservice, making it harder to find correct answers for the tag) and am wondering how to best deal with them? Is the community just supposed to (in the long term) go back and down vote answers that are no longer working or is this just going to result in thousands of questions with out of date information in them?

One idea I had was just to let things run it's cause and then batch retag all the questions to [swift-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-beta) (or similar) once it gets out of beta.

Comment: Will these answers really be outdated, though? Changes to array constant behavior and convenience setup syntax, while significant, did not invalidate most of the code out there. At worst, they created a handful of syntax errors that can be corrected. Adding public / private syntax will be a larger change, but how many questions will that affect? None of us can predict what the future holds with this, but I don't see all of these answers being invalidated in the near future.

Comment: Languages have different versions, which is why the Java8 tag is different from the Java tag, for example. We should be tagging Swift-related questions based on the version in question whenever possible.

Comment: There has been other changes (for example what counts as value types) and there will likely be more changes that we don't know of which will make previous information outdated. There is already about [450 hits for "swift beta"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+beta).

Comment: I also think there is a lot of "is this a bug" questions. Not only for swift but new frameworks that are still in beta. They largely have the same problem.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - I can see a lot of the "is this a bug" questions being closed as "can no longer reproduce" once the bug (which it usually is) is fixed. That's a more general issue with all the beta software here, including the OS versions.

Comment: @BradLarson Looking at [this list of things that are said to change](https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux) I would think that a good amount of answers will get outdated.

Answer (score 1):

How is this different from any other library? The answer for how do you define a bean in Spring 2.0 is very different from what you'd get now that we are at Spring 4.0 ^ . With Swift, it's just a little more extreme, but it's only a difference of degree not essence.

^ 
1. yes, technically it would still work, but XML is now discouraged, and this is just an example
2. people generally don't use version tags correctly, otherwise I'd say just use things like [swift-beta1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-beta1) and [swift-beta2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-beta2)

Comment: Heh, "library".

Answer (score 0):

While this *could* become a major problem, I think that the model that we already have for outdated questions should work fine for this.

A lot of [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) questions are resolved with "this is just a bug" and fixed with the next beta, rendering them useless and obsolete, therefore making a lot of those ~3500 (now ~5500) questions unlikely to show up in search results for common issues.

For those questions that do retain their usefulness, it is up to editors or original answerers to update their answers if they want to keep them relevant and upvote-worthy. Otherwise, new questions will be asked and new answers will gain search result prominence over older ones.

Comment: How does fixing a bug in the next release prevent old questions from showing up in Google searches?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, my point was that hopefully the bug being resolved would decrease the number of people searching for that specific error.