# Burninate [xcode6-beta4]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

People are creating questions tagged [xcode6-beta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6-beta4). This tag will likely be irrelevant within the span of 2 weeks — can we just blacklist it (and similar tags) now?

Comment: Blacklisting has a huge overhead since it's a manual process from the devs. I'm unfamiliar with xcode. Is there a better tag like [xcode6] that the the questions could be retagged with then let the nightly job cleanup the unused [xcode6-beta4]? It looks like [xcode6-beta3] was made a synonym of [xcode6], so that's another option too.

Comment: Is the tag relevant *now*? All you've done is say it won't be relevant at some arbitrary time in the future. It is a valid tag for questions specific to that version of the product while that version exists. The tag will automatically be culled from the system if no questions are using it, or if questions that were using it get closed and deleted.

Comment: @StevenV That's a valid point, but when I try to propose a synonym I simply get "Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators".

Comment: David makes the argument here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265976/how-to-best-deal-with-swift-evolving-very-quickly-and-outdating-information to tag all the in-beta products with that, so we can identify outdated information. I'm not sure I'm a fan of that, but that's at least one argument for it.

Comment: Synonymized to [xcode6]